# how to select multiple column from the table using group by( based on one column) , having and count in hive query

Tags: hiveql, impala

Requirement :
Using group by A and get records having count > 1
eg:

```
SELECT count(sk), id, sk
FROM table x
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(sk) > 1
```

But I am not able to select sk in select statement. Is there any other way to do this. how to use partition on this [input and output set attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcmIZ.png)?

Comment: You can use analytical functions. Your input and output are not clear.Please ask the question according to guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you can do.

```
select * from (
SELECT count(sk)over(partition by id) as cnt, id, sk
FROM table x) a
where a.cnt >1
```